# White space above footer using CSS position:fixed

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position, footer, space

Currently, I am using a text widget with HTML and CSS to create my footer. For some reason, on a specific page on my website there is a huge white space above my footer. The space also increases as the resolution increases. It can mainly been seen starting with resolution widths 1440x900 and up. I am sure it has something to do with my footer but I am not sure what exactly.

Can be seen here: http://museiam.ca/vault/

Footer CSS:

```
.gbtr_dark_footer_wrapper .container_12 .grid_3 {
    z-index:99999 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255);
    background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I'm not really sure what else you would expect to happen with `position:fixed;bottom:0`

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is fixed to the bottom of the window due to

```
.gbtr_dark_footer_wrapper .container_12 .grid_3 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

As your resolution increases, the content will fill up only the top of the page, and the footer will stay at the bottom, leaving a huge whitespace in between.

Comment: So how would I go about keeping the footer fixed at the bottom with out causing this issue? I am unsure of how to fix. If I remove either I loose the footer or it does not stay fixed in the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Add more content to the page so that it fills up the white space.